# How are Kars' features described in this image?

Tags: japanese-language, jojos-bizarre-adventure

When Kars becomes the ultimate life form, There is an image which points out each of Kars' new features - 400 IQ, 18m jumping etc.

[image]

Can someone help translate what his other skills are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [2ch post](http://www.logsoku.com/r/news4vip/1365251852/6) has bigger image.

- Intelligence: IQ is 400.
- Haptic sense: Can feel the movement of heat and air.
- Hearing ability: Can here the ululation of animals from bats to whales.
- Visual acuity: Like astrometric telescope.
- Born: Breakdown to each cell and transform into many breeds.
- Muscle: Recuperate from wounds very soon, then can transform/heal very quickly.
- Gripping power: 900 kg/cm^2
- Jumping power: 18m
- Favourite food: Humans that became bloodsuckers. (Can survive without the need of any food and drink for 1 year.)
- Sleep: No need.
- Objective of breed: Other breed has a objective that creates descendants. But in his case creates a world that he thinks.
- SEX: No need. lower forms of life need many children. It's easy to die. No need for child or friend for perfect life. "Top" is always only one.
- Baby of the human was transformed 9 hundred million evolution in 10 month.
  DNA know it. Like this, cell of his body know all DNA of all breed. he can transform to any breed.